# Improper alignment in tabular environment when using xcolor table option

Tags: tables, beamer, horizontal-alignment, color

I came across weird behavior when loading `xcolor=table` option that affects the proper alignement in the tabular environment.

The output of this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l|ccc@{}}
        \toprule 
        \multirow{2}{*}{\huge Parameters} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Levels}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
                             & 1   & 2   & 3   \\ 
        \midrule
        Power \hfill \si{\W} & 100 & 200 & 300 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

is

[image]

However, when using the option `\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}`, I got the output like this with improper alignment in the first cell of the last row.

[image]

How can I got the proper alignment with loading this option `xcolor=table`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use two columns instead of one:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrccc@{}}
\toprule 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\huge Parameters}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Levels}\\
                \cmidrule{3-5}
      &         & 1   & 2   & 3   \\ 
\midrule
Power & \si{\W} & 100 & 200 & 300 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}lrccc@{}}
\toprule 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Levels}\\
                \cmidrule{3-5}
      &         & 1   & 2   & 3   \\ 
\midrule
Power & \si{\W} & 100 & 200 & 300 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I suggest you to consider the second table, without the humongous `\huge` label.

[image]

Alternatively, in your code, write

```
Power\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}\si{W}
```

---

The TeXnical reason is that `colortbl` (loaded with the `table` option to `xcolor`) realizes left alignment with `\hfill` rather than with `\hfil` as the core code. Thus you need a higher order infinite glue to push the object to the right margin.

Comment: Many thanks for your simple solution. I just used `\huge` to magnify the gap before the vertical rule.